# 開発環境、EC2環境で共通のコードで別の権限で S3 にアクセスしたい

Tags: ruby, aws, amazon-s3

ruby で aws-sdk gem を使って S3 にアクセスするプログラムがあるのですが
EC2 で動かす分には EC2 Role を割り当てて

```
Aws::S3::Client.new
```

と引数なしで動くのですが EC2 ではない開発環境でこのプログラムを動かしたとき
引数なしの s3 クライアントの credentials は何を参照するのでしょうか

ローカルのPC上の開発環境で共通のコードを動くようにするには

```
if ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] && ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  )
else
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
end
```

のように分岐をかいて毎回キーペアをセットするしかないですか？

aws cli は

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=default
aws s3 ls

export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=staging
aws s3 ls
```

のように環境変数にプロファイル名をいれるだけで見る先をかえてくれるのですが
ruby プログラムをこのような形で動かすことはできないでしょうか

よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html#aws-ruby-sdk-credentials-environment

上記に記述がありますが、 `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` 環境変数と `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` 環境変数を、それぞれ設定したならば、 S3 クライアントのセットアップは、特に何も行う必要がなく、すなわち、引数なしでただただ new をすれば良いと思います。

Comment: ソースに分岐をかく必要はないけど、プロファイル名ではなく必ずキーペアを環境変数に設定する必要はあるということでしょうか

Comment: 自分の覚えている限りの挙動ですと、 1. プログラムで明示的に指定されればその接続情報を 2. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID と SECRET が環境変数指定されていればそれを 3. PROFILE が環境変数で与えられていれば、 aws configure で作成されたプロファイルを 4. aws configure のデフォルトプロファイル 5. エラー   だったような気がします。

Comment: `export AWS_PROFILE=staging` でできました　DEFAULT_AWS_PROFILE ではなかったのですね　ありがとうございました